# Replacing old for New Honeywell thermostat

Tags: wiring, thermostat

[image]
Old thermostat had a jumper between RH
And RC, iam replacing that with a Honeywell
Programmable thermostat, but idk if 
I should replace this jumper on new ther
mostat ? And if so, should I remove 
Metal jumper  (already in place) on new thermostat?  No clue what I’m doing

Comment: What model is your new 'stat?

Comment: What do the directions for the new thermostat say?

Answer (score 2):

RH & RC are jumpered at the factory because most systems have only one transformer whether that is heating or cooling or both. If this is the case with your system, leave the jumper in place.  If you have a heating system combined with a cooling system and if both of those systems have their own transformer or if you have any two different system controlled by one thermostat and they have separate transformers then and only then do you pull the jumper.

Answer (score 0):

If you have forced air heat, then you'll likely leave the jumper in place.  If you have radiant heat, you might have separate transformers.  However, since the jumper is currently in place, you'll almost certainly want to leave have it on the new thermostat.

---

## Further reading

`Rc` is the terminal that connects to one leg of the control transformer, from the cooling system. `Rh` is similar, though connects to one leg of the heating system.  If your system only has a single control transformer (typical in forced air systems), you'll only have one `R` wire coming to the thermostat.  Since there's only one `R` wire, you'll need a jumper to get power to both `Rc` and `Rh`.

If your system has two separate control transformers, you'll have two `R` wires coming to the thermostat. In this case, you'll remove the jumper and connect the `R` wires to their respective terminals.